# How to generate SelectManyCheckbox (primefaces) from the server?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to generate dynamically some components from the server and I have a problem with SelectManyCheckbox. I need to add a list of selectitems into it but there is no such method available. Maybe someone can help me, maybe I choose wrong direction.
Example:

```
SelectManyCheckbox checkbox = new SelectManyCheckbox();
List<SelectItem> items
```

items - the list that must be displayed as selectItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to add them programmatically. The key is to add them as children. One way to do it could be like this:

```
List<SelectItem> items; //Your items
SelectManyCheckbox checkbox = new SelectManyCheckbox();
UISelectItems selectItems = new UISelectItems();
selectItems.setValue(items);
checkbox.getChildren().add(selectItems);
```

Comment: And what about the method setSelectedValues? As I see, as the parameter in it there must be an Array. I putted there array of selectItems but id does not work.

Comment: @Viktoriia It should be an array of values (whatever match with your SelectItem values, String for example), not an array of SelectItem

Comment: in my case it is a list of doubles. By this way does not work

Comment: With an array like Double[] doesn't work? Maybe you should add another question with all the code and specific details :)

Answer (score 0):

The `value` of `<f:selectItems` of a `<p:selectManyCheckbox` can be populated with objects of `SelectItem`:

> Value expression pointing at any `Collection`
>                   or array. The member elements may be instances of
>                   `SelectItem` or any Java Object.

## Example

### page.xhtml

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

### Bean.java

```
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@ViewScoped
@Named
public class Bean {

    public List<SelectItem> getItems() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```